# Function call not accepting :: operator in argument

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm supposed to write a recursive functional concatenation function in Scala without using standard list operators.

```
def myConcat: (List[Any],List[Any]) => List[Any] = {
  case (xs,Nil) => xs
  case (xs,y::ys) => myConcat(xs::y,ys)
}
```

which throws the error

```
         case (xs,y::ys) => myConcat(xs::y,ys)
                                       ^
Recursion.scala:3: error: value :: is not a member of Any
```

I am rather confident that this would, but that I am misunderstanding something about the syntax/typing. To the best of my knowledge xs::y should be of type List[Any].

Comment: Apparently the :: operator will only prepend and not append. Still unsure how I am intended to solve this considering I am not allowed to use the ::: or append functions.

Comment: `y` is an `A` and `xs` is a `List[A]` and you are trying to call `::` on the `A` and pass as argument a `List[A]`, that won't work. - About how to solve the problem, try looking it at the other way, concatenating `ys` to `xs` is the same as prepending `xs` to `ys`

Comment: `case (xs; Nil) => xs; case (xs, y :: yx) => myConcat(y :: xs, ys)` for `(Nil, ys)` is virtually `reverse`. `reverse(reverse(list))` is `identity` with extra steps. You can arrange: local tail rec def, 2 list of inputs, 1 list as accumulator, and custom `reverse` to concatenate things without extra methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, you cannot use `List.reverse` either, so, start with implementing that:

```
    @tailrec
    def reverse(in: List[Any], out: List[Any]): List[Any] = in match {
      case Nil => out
      case head::tail => reverse(tail, head::out)
   }
```

Now,  for concat:

```
    @tailrec
    def concatReversed(x: List[Any], y: List[Any]): List[Any] = x match {
       case Nil => y
       case head::tail => concatReversed(tail, head::y)
    }

    def concat(x: List[Any], y: List[Any]) = 
      concatReversed(reverse(x, List.empty[Any]), y)
```

If you are not looking for the solution to be tail-recursive, it makes things simpler (albeit less efficient):

```
     def concat(x: List[Any], y: List[Any]): List[Any] = x match {
       case Nil => y
       case head ::  tail => head :: concat(tail, y)
     }
```

Comment: Yeah, we aren't allowed to use "List functions", I assume reverse belongs to those. Should've come up with the reverse idea myself, thanks :D